# Performance Monitor connect to server on a different domain

Tags: sql-server, perfmon

I've been using PerfMon to monitor some SQL Server Stats for a while but we recently moved our production SQL Server to a different domain and I'm having trouble setting this back up. When I try to add the counters in it recognises it but then when I expand a section I get `Can't Load Counters`.

We have a trust between the domain and I've added my local login account to the 'Perf Monitor Users' & 'Perf Log Users' group on the destination domain.

[image]

Anyone had this before or got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this question is old but I had to finesse an answer under slightly different circumstances. This won't address domain trust issues. Still, given the number of views, I thought this was worthy of sharing. It worked for me on a Windows 7 machine.

- Credit this answer for portions of this: [How can I save the counters’ setup in windows performance monitor](https://serverfault.com/questions/339282/how-can-i-save-the-counters-setup-in-windows-performance-monitor)

**General**

1. Elevate a cmd.exe's privileges (*Run as Administrator*) so you can `runas` another user.
2. From the elevated command window, open a `cmd` window under the desired credentials, e.g. (`runas /user:<doman>\<user> cmd`).
3. From the command window with the desired credentials run `mmc` (NOT `PerfMon` directly).

   - If you don't do this I don't see how to save the changes you make.
4. In the MMC (Console) add the Performance Monitor snap-in (File | Add/Remove Snap-in...).
5. Now you should be able to access the desired server(s) with the desired credentials. Also you can now save your work (File | Save As...).

**In Windows 7**

1. **Start**, type `cmd` (*search programs and files*), right-click on the resulting **cmd.exe** and select **Run as administrator**. Accept the elevated privileges prompt (**User Account Control** dialog).
2. In the resulting command window (**Administrator: C:\Windows\System32\Cmd.exe**), enter `runas /user:<domain>\<user> cmd`.
3. In the resulting command window, "`cmd (running as <domain>\\<user>)`", type `mmc`
4. In the resulting mmc window, "`Console1 - [Console Root]`", chose **File** | **Add Remove Snap-in...**, select **Performance Monitor**.
5. Add your counters and now you can also save them.